# Are there any MVC Visualizers out there?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debuggervisualizer

Are there any debug visualizers for Visual Studio for MVC?

Would be great to be able to visualize things like ModelState, ViewState, Routes etc.

If you're interested in this just favorite the question. If it gets a lot of favorites I'll think about writing one

Answer (score 1):

Not a debugger - visualizer but shows the complete ViewModel on the page: The ModelVisualizer in MVC Contrib.

Answer (score 0):

See this two links:

- [Visualizers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts.aspx)
- [Create a Debugger Visualizer in Visual Studio 2005 for Custom Types and Classes](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/12/26/2645.aspx)

Regards.